# View cshtml code with angular in web page

Tags: c#, angularjs

I've got emails in a database. Those emails are written in CSHTML. I want to show them in my webpage (using AngularJS) in an IFrame (since nothing else works), like a preview from an email. Here is an example from an email in code.

```
<!doctype html>\r\n
<html>
   \r\n
   <head>
      \r\n
      <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\">
      \r\n
      <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">
      \r\n
      <title>Really Simple HTML Email Template</title>
      \r\n
      <style>\r\n/* -------------------------------------\r\n    GLOBAL\r\n------------------------------------- */\r\n* {\r\n  font-family: \"Helvetica Neue\", \"Helvetica\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\r\n  font-size: 100%;\r\n  line-height: 1.6em;\r\n  margin: 0;\r\n  padding: 0;\r\n}\r\nimg {\r\n  max-width: 600px;\r\n  width: auto;\r\n}\r\nbody {\r\n  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;\r\n  height: 100%;\r\n  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;\r\n  width: 100% !important;\r\n}\r\n/* -------------------------------------\r\n    ELEMENTS\r\n------------------------------------- */\r\na {\r\n  color: #348eda;\r\n}\r\n.btn-primary {\r\n  Margin-bottom: 10px;\r\n  width: auto !important;\r\n}\r\n.btn-primary td {\r\n  background-color: #348eda;\r\n  border-radius: 10px;\r\n  font-family: \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, Arial, \"Lucida Grande\", sans-serif;\r\n  font-size: 14px;\r\n  text-align: center;\r\n  vertical-align: top;\r\n}\r\n.btn-primary td a {\r\n  background-color: #348eda;\r\n  border: solid 1px #348eda;\r\n  border-radius: 25px;\r\n  border-width: 7px 20px;\r\n  display: inline-block;\r\n  color: #ffffff;\r\n  cursor: pointer;\r\n  font-weight: bold;\r\n  line-height: 2;\r\n  text-decoration: none;\r\n}\r\n.last {\r\n  margin-bottom: 0;\r\n}\r\n.first {\r\n  margin-top: 0;\r\n}\r\n.padding {\r\n  padding: 10px 0;\r\n}\r\n/* -------------------------------------\r\n    BODY\r\n------------------------------------- */\r\ntable.body-wrap {\r\n  padding: 20px;\r\n  width: 100%;\r\n}\r\ntable.body-wrap .container {\r\n  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;\r\n}\r\n/* -------------------------------------\r\n    FOOTER\r\n------------------------------------- */\r\ntable.footer-wrap {\r\n  clear: both !important;\r\n  width: 100%;\r\n}\r\n.footer-wrap .container p {\r\n  color: #666666;\r\n  font-size: 12px;\r\n\r\n}\r\ntable.footer-wrap a {\r\n  color: #999999;\r\n}\r\n/* -------------------------------------\r\n    TYPOGRAPHY\r\n------------------------------------- */\r\nh1,\r\nh2,\r\nh3 {\r\n  color: #111111;\r\n  font-family: \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, Arial, \"Lucida Grande\", sans-serif;\r\n  font-weight: 200;\r\n  line-height: 1.2em;\r\n  margin: 40px 0 10px;\r\n}\r\nh1 {\r\n  font-size: 36px;\r\n}\r\nh2 {\r\n  font-size: 28px;\r\n}\r\nh3 {\r\n  font-size: 22px;\r\n}\r\np,\r\nul,\r\nol {\r\n  font-size: 14px;\r\n  font-weight: normal;\r\n  margin-bottom: 10px;\r\n}\r\nul li,\r\nol li {\r\n  margin-left: 5px;\r\n  list-style-position: inside;\r\n}\r\n/* ---------------------------------------------------\r\n    RESPONSIVENESS\r\n------------------------------------------------------ */\r\n/* Set a max-width, and make it display as block so it will automatically stretch to that width, but will also shrink down on a phone or something */\r\n.container {\r\n  clear: both !important;\r\n  display: block !important;\r\n  Margin: 0 auto !important;\r\n  max-width: 600px !important;\r\n}\r\n/* Set the padding on the td rather than the div for Outlook compatibility */\r\n.body-wrap .container {\r\n  padding: 20px;\r\n}\r\n/* This should also be a block element, so that it will fill 100% of the .container */\r\n.content {\r\n  display: block;\r\n  margin: 0 auto;\r\n  max-width: 600px;\r\n}\r\n/* Let's make sure tables in the content area are 100% wide */\r\n.content table {\r\n  width: 100%;\r\n}\r\n</style>
      \r\n
   </head>
   \r\n\r\n
   <body bgcolor=\"#f6f6f6\">
      \r\n\r\n<!-- body -->\r\n
      <table class=\"body-wrap\" bgcolor=\"#f6f6f6\">
         \r\n
         <tr>
            \r\n
            <td></td>
            \r\n
            <td class=\"container\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">
               \r\n<!-- content -->\r\n
               <div class=\"content\">
                  \r\n    
                  <table>
                     \r\n        
                     <tr>
                        \r\n            
                        <td>
                           \r\n                
                           <center>\r\n                    <img src=\"logo-about.jpg\" />\r\n                </center>
                           \r\n            
                        </td>
                        \r\n        
                     </tr>
                     \r\n        \r\n\r\n
                     <tr>
                        \r\n    
                        <td>
                           \r\n        
                           <center>
                              \r\n            
                              <h1>Password Reset</h1>
                              \r\n            <br>\r\n            
                              <p>\r\n                <b>Username:</b> Larissa<br>\r\n                <b>New Password:</b> dsFCPrsn\r\n            </p>
                              \r\n            <br>\r\n\r\n            <!-- button -->\r\n            
                              <table class=\"btn-primary\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\">
                                 \r\n                
                                 <tr>
                                    \r\n                
                                    <td>\r\n                    <a href=\"http://localhost:29870/auth/login\">Login</a>\r\n                </td>
                                    \r\n                
                                 </tr>
                                 \r\n            
                              </table>
                              \r\n        
                           </center>
                           \r\n    
                        </td>
                        \r\n
                     </tr>
                     \r\n\r\n\r\n    
                  </table>
                  \r\n      
               </div>
               \r\n      <!-- /content -->\r\n\r\n    
            </td>
            \r\n    
            <td></td>
            \r\n  
         </tr>
         \r\n
      </table>
      \r\n<!-- /body -->\r\n\r\n<!-- footer -->\r\n
      <table class=\"footer-wrap\">
         \r\n  
         <tr>
            \r\n    
            <td></td>
            \r\n    
            <td class=\"container\">\r\n\r\n\r\n    </td>
            \r\n    
            <td></td>
            \r\n  
         </tr>
         \r\n
      </table>
      \r\n<!-- /footer -->\r\n\r\n
   </body>
   \r\n
</html>
```

If I show them in a simple iframe with srcdoc, it just looks plain ugly with lots of \r and \n's.

Comment: \r and \n are not html so will be displayed as shown. Can't you just do some string manipulation to remove them from the string before displaying it?

Comment: Since it's CSHTML what the Razor engine does is save the views as C# classes, in which there is a string that generates the html. To keep formatting Razor uses `\r\n` to drop a new line for when the view gets compiled. Is there a reason why it has to be a CSHTML page if you're sending it in an email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to ways to do this. Either save this document with .html form and assign source url to direct iframe like this :

```
$scope.tabs = [{ title: 'Document 1', content: '<iframe src="../data/data.html"  width="1000" height="900"></iframe>' }];
```

Another way to to get html content via ajax call, like this:

```
myApp.controller('TabsCtrl', function ($scope, $window, $http, $sce) {
   var url = "../data/data.html";
   $http.get(url).success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.myData= $sce.trustAsHtml(data); // for html parsing
    });
});
```

And html will look like this

```
  <uib-tabset active="active">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Static title"><div ng-bind-html="myData"></div></uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset
```